# compute tf-idf with corpus

Tags: python, tf-idf

So, I have copied a source code about how to create a system that can run tf-idf, and here is the code :

```
    #module import
    from __future__ import division, unicode_literals
    import math
    import string
    import re
    import os

    from text.blob import TextBlob as tb
    #create a new array
    words = {} 
    def tf(word, blob):
       return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

    def n_containing(word, bloblist):
       return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

    def idf(word, bloblist):
       return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

    def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
       return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)

    regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))

    f = open('D:/article/sport/a.txt','r')
    var = f.read()
    var = regex.sub(' ', var)
    var = var.lower()

    document1 = tb(var)

    f = open('D:/article/food/b.txt','r')
    var = f.read()
    var = var.lower()
    document2 = tb(var)


    bloblist = [document1, document2]
    for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
       print("Top words in document {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for word, score in sorted_words[:50]:
    print("Word: {}, TF-IDF: {}".format(word, round(score, 5)))
```

but, the problem is, i want to put all of the files in the sport folder in a corpora, and 
the food article in the food folder into another corpora, so the the system will give a result for each corpora. Now, i can only compare files, but i want to compare between corpora.I am very sorry for asking this question, any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: i accidentally pressed the button :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i got is that, you want to calculate the word frequency of two file and store them in different file to compare them, to do this , you can use terminal. Here is the simple code to calculate the word frequency

```
import string
import collections
import operator
keywords = []
i=0
def removePunctuation(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    new_sentence = ""
    for char in sentence:
        if char not in string.punctuation:
                new_sentence = new_sentence + char
    return new_sentence
 def wordFrequences(sentence):
    global i
    wordFreq = {}
    split_sentence = new_sentence.split()
    for word in split_sentence:
        wordFreq[word] = wordFreq.get(word,0) + 1
    wordFreq.items()
  # od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(wordFreq.items(),reverse=True))
  # print od
    sorted_x= sorted(wordFreq.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse = True)
    print sorted_x
    for key, value in sorted_x:
        keywords.append(key)
    print keywords
f = open('D:/article/sport/a.txt','r')
sentence = f.read()
# sentence = "The first test of the function some some some some"
new_sentence = removePunctuation(sentence)
wordFrequences(new_sentence)
```

you have to run this code two time by changing the path of your text file and each time when you run code from console pass command like this

```
python abovecode.py > destinationfile.txt
```

like in your case

```
python abovecode.py > sportfolder/file1.txt
python abovecode.py > foodfolder/file2.txt
```

imp : if u want the words with their frequency then omit the part

```
print keywords
```

imp : if u need words acc. to their freq then omit

```
print sorted_x
```