# Using directory as input for tf-idf with python `textblob`

Tags: python, glob, textblob

I am trying to adapt this code (source found [here](http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/))to iterate through a directory of files, instead of having the input hard-coded.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division, unicode_literals
import math
from textblob import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
    return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)


document1 = tb("""Today, the weather is 30 degrees in Celcius. It is really hot""")

document2 = tb("""I can't believe the traffic headed to the beach. It is really a circus out there.'""")

document3 = tb("""There are so many tolls on this road. I recommend taking the interstate.""")

bloblist = [document1, document2, document3]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Document {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for word, score in sorted_words:
        score_weight = score * 100 
        print("\t{}, {}".format(word, round(score_weight, 5)))
```

I would like to use an an input txt files in a directory, rather than each hard-coded `document`.

For instance, imagine I had a directory `foo` which contains three files `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.

File 1 contains the contents that `document1` contains, i.e.

file1:

```
Today, the weather is 30 degrees in Celcius. It is really hot
```

File 2 contains the contents that `document2` contains, i.e.

```
I can't believe the traffic headed to the beach. It is really a circus out there.
```

File 3 contains the contents that `document3` contains, i.e.

```
There are so many tolls on this road. I recommend taking the interstate.
```

I have though to use `glob` to achieve my desired result, and I have come up with the following code adapation, which correctly identifies the files, but does not process them individually, as the original code does:

```
file_names = glob.glob("/path/to/foo/*")
files =  map(open,file_names)
documents = [file.read() for file in files]
[file.close() for file in files]


bloblist = [documents]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Document {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for word, score in sorted_words:
        score_weight = score * 100 
        print("\t{}, {}".format(word, round(score_weight, 5)))
```

How can I maintain the scores for each individual file using `glob`?

The desired result after using the files in a directory as input would be the same as the original code [results truncuated to top 3 for space]:

```
Document 1
    Celcius, 3.37888
    30, 3.37888
    hot, 3.37888
Document 2
    there, 2.38509
    out, 2.38509
    headed, 2.38509
Document 3
    on, 3.11896
    this, 3.11896
    many, 3.11896
```

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434092/compute-tf-idf-with-corpus) did not fully solve the problem. I was wondering how I can call the files to calculate the `idf` but maintain them separately for calculate the full `tf-idf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code example you fill `bloblist` with results of `tb()`, and in your second example - with inputs for `tb()` (just strings).

Try to replace `bloblist = [documents]` with `bloblist = map(tb, documents)`.

You can also sort filename list like this `file_names = sorted(glob.glob("/path/to/foo/*"))` to make outputs of both versions match.

Answer (score 1):

@AnnaBonazzi provides a code snippet here, https://gist.github.com/sloria/6407257,

```
import os, glob
folder = "/path/to/folder/"
os.chdir(folder)
files = glob.glob("*.txt") # Makes a list of all files in folder
bloblist = []
for file1 in files:
    with open (file1, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read() # Reads document content into a string
        document = tb(data.decode("utf-8")) # Makes TextBlob object
        bloblist.append(document)
```

I modified it for my use (Python 3):

```
import os, glob
bloblist = []

def make_corpus(input_dir):
    """ Based on code snippet from https://gist.github.com/sloria/6407257 """

    global doc                              ## used outside this method
    input_folder = "input"
    os.chdir(input_folder)
    files = glob.glob("*.*")                ## or "*.txt", etc.
    for doc in files:
        # print('doc:', doc)                ## prints filename (doc)
        with open (doc, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()                 ## read document content into a string
            document = tb(data)             ## make TextBlob object
            bloblist.append(document)
    # print('bloblist:\n', bloblist)        ## copious output ...
    print('len(bloblist):', len(bloblist))


make_corpus('input')                        ## input directory 'input'
```

---

**Update 1:**

I personally have nothing but difficulty using the Python glob module, as I often (i) have filenames without extensions (e.g. 01), and (ii) want to recurse over nested directories.

At first glance the "glob" approach appears to be a simple solution.  However, when trying to iterate over the files in that are returned by glob, I often encounter errors (e.g.)

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: ...
```

when the loop encounters a directory (not a file) name that was returned by glob.

In my opinion, with a little added effort, the following approach is far more robust:

```
import os
bloblist = []

def make_corpus(input_dir):
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
        for filename in files:
            f = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print('file:', f)
            with open(os.path.join(root, filename)) as f:
                for line in f:
                    # print(line, end='')
                    bloblist.append(line)
    # print('bloblist:\n', bloblist)
    print('len(bloblist):', len(bloblist), '\n')

make_corpus('input')       ## 'input' = input dir
```

---

**Update 2:**

One last approach (Linux shell `find` command, adapted for use in Python 3):

```
import sh     ## pip install sh

def make_corpus(input_dir):
    '''find (here) matches filenames, excludes directory names'''

    corpus = []
    file_list = []
    #FILES = sh.find(input_dir, '-type', 'f', '-iname', '*.txt')    ## find all .txt files
    FILES = sh.find(input_dir, '-type', 'f', '-iname', '*')         ## find any file
    print('FILES:', FILES)                                          ## caveat: files in FILES are '\n'-terminated ...
    for filename in FILES:
        #print(filename, end='')
        # file_list.append(filename)                                ## when printed, each filename ends with '\n'
        filename = filename.rstrip('\n')                            ## ... this addresses that issue
        file_list.append(filename)
        with open(filename) as f:
            #print('file:', filename)
            # ----------------------------------------
            # for general use:
            #for line in f:
                #print(line)
                #corpus.append(line)
            # ----------------------------------------
            # for this particular example (Question, above):
            data = f.read()
            document = tb(data)
            corpus.append(document)
    print('file_list:', file_list)
    print('corpus length (lines):', len(corpus))

    with open('output/corpus', 'w') as f:                           ## write to file
        for line in corpus:
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is exactly what you want to achieve.
You could have an array and append the results to that array:

```
scores = []
bloblist = [documents]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
  ... do your evaluation ..
  scores.append(score_weight)

print scores
```